# Is there a word that means to smoke but not to inhale?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

I'm trying to translate this term from Chinese:

> #### 包口烟   *bāo kǒu yān*   [pau⁵⁵ kʰou̯⁵²³ i̯εn⁵⁵]
>
> (名) 抽烟不吸进肺里。 ▷ 抽包口烟。
> (n.) Mouthful of smoke that is not inhaled into the lungs. ▷ Smoke a *bāo kǒu yān*.

So a 包口烟 is basically what you draw into your mouth when you smoke without inhaling. It’s a mouthful of smoke that you blow out instead of letting it go into your lungs.

包口烟 is a noun describing the smoke itself; the verb 吸 *xī* or 抽 *chōu* is used to indicate the action, just like with the regular expression meaning ‘to smoke’: 吸烟 *xī yān* or 抽烟 *chōu yān*, literally ‘draw/pull smoke’. Here you just ‘draw/pull mouthful-of-non-inhaled-smoke’ instead.

Is there a noun that means *mouthful of non-inhaled smoke* in English? Or a verb that refers to drawing smoke from a cigarette (or similar) without letting it enter your lungs? Or a term for someone who smokes in this way, for that matter?

Comment: I would call them a non-inhaling smoker. I don't think that there is any other term that isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @Mick Oh yes there is:  Bill Clinton's dictum - I didn't inhale! We won't go into his other, more infamous dictum on Monica's version of what transpired in the Oval Office.  I have been very careful to avoid any typos with Oral Office. Easily done, innit?

Comment: @PeterPoint *To Clinton*, then. Sorted!

Comment: Ahhhh! You beat me to it!

Comment: Nice verbage: to Clinton! I guess we can always couple it with to do/to pull.

Comment: Filling your mouth is still a kind of inhaling...

Comment: "Rationalizing" is the usual term.

Answer (score 2):

I often hear this referred to as "puffing," as in "Puffing on a cigar," or "Puffing a cigar." However, "puffing" is still vague enough that it doesn't always convey that the smoke isn't being inhaled to the lungs. More often than not, it's just slang for smoking.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard "bum puffing" for this. Although that has a negative connotation, as in it is smoking 'for show' or not really smoking.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).